# Dialogflow: Small talk without losing context

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am developing a bot with Dialogflow. Sometimes, the user may diverge from conversation and ask small talk. However, when this activates a small talk intent, some contexts may expire. How can I activate a small intent, but keep the previous activated intents at their same lifespan?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

each context has a lifespan which determines after how many matched intents the context disappears. The default value is 5.

A possible solution is to set the context lifespan to a higher value, it does not seem possible to make a given context lifespan independent from the others.

You can set the lifespan in the DialogFlow UI or via the webhook, but be aware that it will anyway expire after 20 min.

Comment: I see, I wonder why Google has not see independent intents that don't affect the flow of contexts.

Comment: I guess they want to keep it simple, not sure they are interested in making DialogFlow a perfect platform, just interested in the data that goes through 